# Ubuntu 21.10 on Dell XPS 17 9700 WiFi Killer AX500s DBS stopped working in kernel 5.13.0-21-generic

Tags: networking, dual-boot, kernel, uefi, dell

This is essentially the same question as that from axtimwalde.
I bought the XPS 17 9700 in April and after a lot of struggling got it to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 21.04 (having failed with 20.04 LTS).
Then a week or two ago, I ran apt upgrade and the wifi adaptor disappeared in Ubuntu.  It also went in Windows 10, so I assumed a hardware failure and contacted Dell hardware support.  After some tests in Windows 10, they assured me that the hardware was OK and it must be a software problem.
I've since fiddled with the UEFI settings and Windows seems to be OK, but still nothing in Ubuntu.  Having read that others had similar problems, I tried upgrading to 21.10, but still no joy.  I can still use Ubuntu with a USB WiFi adaptor, or tethered to a phone.
I've tried the commands in the XPS 13 post with similar results.
I'm not a Linux expert, so I'm reluctant to do anything complicated.
So, the question is: is there likely to be an update with a fix in this release, or even 22.04 LTS which I hope to move to?  If so, I'll just wait.  Or, is there something relatively simple that I can do now?

Comment: So, first of all, should we assume the WiFi is working in Windows? It isn't clear. That being the case try disabling Fast Startup in Windows, a must when dual-booting. Also a firmware (UEFI) update may have re-enabled a previously disable Secure Boot in UEFI. Check both before anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response.  
1. Yes, wifi works fine in Windows 10.  
2. As you say, I had to disable Fast Startup to get dual-boot to work, which it does.
3. Secure Boot is disabled.

Comment: Here are the tests performed by axtimwalde:

Comment: sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA6390 Wireless Network Adapter [AX500-DBS (2x2)]
       vendor: Qualcomm
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ath11k_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:195 memory:d2100000-d21fffff

Comment: *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: usb0
       serial: ee:bb:d2:dd:31:4f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.13.0-21-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.64.216 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair

Comment: sudo lspci | grep Qualcomm
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm QCA6390 Wireless Network Adapter [AX500-DBS (2x2)] (rev 01)

Comment: sudo modprobe ath11k_pci

sudo dmesg | grep ath11
[    2.909611] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xd2100000-0xd21fffff 64bit]
[    2.909642] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.909951] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: qca6390 hw2.0
[    8.250584] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to register fw indication: -110
[    8.250609] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to send qmi firmware indication: -110

sudo rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: sudo modprobe -r ath11k_pci && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe ath11k_pci && sudo dmesg | grep ath11
[    3.809331] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xd2100000-0xd21fffff 64bit]
[    3.809359] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.809667] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: qca6390 hw2.0
[    9.267238] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to register fw indication: -110
[    9.267245] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to send qmi firmware indication: -110
[ 1247.898883] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: link down error during global reset

Comment: [ 1253.432536] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xd2100000-0xd21fffff 64bit]
[ 1253.433522] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: qca6390 hw2.0
[ 1253.486566] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to set pcie link register 0x01e0c0ac: 0xffffffff != 0x00000010
[ 1253.486569] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: failed to set sysclk: -110
[ 1253.506739] ath11k_pci 0000:04:00.0: link down error during global reset

Comment: I guess that there isn't currently a solution and I'll have to wait until these Dell laptops become more common and the developers fix the at11 driver (if that's the problem).  My last Dell was the XPS 13 Ubuntu version and I gather that they fitted different WiFi adapters.  Pity they don't do it for a 17" version.  Meanwhile, I'm using a USB adapter.  Messy, but it works.

Comment: I own a Dell XPS 17 9700 also since May. I am on Ubuntu 20.04.3 Had some problems with Mic and Wifi as well, installed a "beta" kernel and then after a while the new standard kernel and everything worked fine until I realised yesterday that Wifi again is not working.

Comment: Well, it now seems to be working.

Comment: I've been abroad for a three weeks and have used a USB dongle.  Came home last night and this morning all is working at 5GHz on my Ubiquity Amplifi mesh.  I've done a couple of apt upgrades whilst away and installed Nvidia GPU drivers, but I hadn't tried without the dongle on the 2.4GHz network where I was staying.